# Run jar file from the console with this input

Tags: java, jar, console, command-prompt, runnable

The input I'm forced to use is like this:

```
java -cp lucene.jar:myjarfile.jar here.my.class.Hello inputFile.gz
```

does anybody know what this mean?

1) lucene.jar:myjarfile.jar = means that you should run "myjarfile.jar" using that library (since Lucene is a library).

2) here.my.class.Hello inputFile.gz = means run the `class Hello` and with input for the constructor of the class use inputFile.gz.

Is that correct?

my question is:

- The `class Hello` must have a constructor that takes a String as a path (.gz file in my case), but should it contain also a main method? and Where should I call the method run() (in the `class Hello`) that make the needed changes possible? in the constructor?

pretty confused, it works very good on the shell but I have a lot of doubts about the console.

e.g. could this work?

```
public class Hello
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        FileReader ready = new FileReader(args[0], "destination");
        ready.run();
    }
}
```

- args[0] should contain `inputFile.gz` now right?

Answer (score 0):

The class Hello should have a main(...) method, and the argument to that main method will include the string after the class name on the command line (inputFile.gz)

Answer (score 0):

you take `inputFile.gz` file as the index 0 input in `String args[]`.

The class `Hello` should have a `main` method. you can call the `run` method in `main` method.

if your pragram is multi threaded, call the `start()` method in Thread in the `main()` method

Comment: @Matt: why don't you run the code. check whether it gives desired result or not?